# Python argparse as a function

Tags: python, function, argparse

Is there anything inherently wrong with getting command-line arguments in this way?  I mean by putting the argument parsing into its own function.  Would it be considered non-Pythonic or more so?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse

def getArgs(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="calculate X to the power of Y")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true")
    group.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("x", type=int, help="the base")
    parser.add_argument("y", type=int, help="the exponent")
    return parser.parse_args(argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    argvals = None             # init argv in case not testing
    argvals = '6 2 -v'.split() # example of passing test params to parser
    args = getArgs(argvals)

    answer = args.x**args.y

    if args.quiet:
        print answer
    elif args.verbose:
        print "{} to the power {} equals {}".format(args.x, args.y, answer)
    else:
        print "{}^{} == {}".format(args.x, args.y, answer)
```

Comment: Nope, that's just fine.

Comment: You could use a single option for verbosity but, as you have 3 levels of it, it may not be more comprehensible.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - Thanks for the feedback about the verbosity.  The base example comes from https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#conflicting-options.  Was really asking about putting the argparse block inside a function as opposed to it being 'naked'.  Seems to me my example is more Pythonic but I could not locate any examples of anyone else doing it.  Hence my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks good, feels good, conforms to [Python Zen](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - so, what's the problem if you didn't see *this particular code* like that?

Moving a somewhat independent piece of functionality into a subroutine is essential good practice - a manifestation of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), to be precise. It's not even about Python.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it confirms the philosophy. Thanks, @ivan_pozdeev!

Answer (score 8):

This is fine. The only suggestion I would make is to allow `get_args` to take as a parameter (`None` by default) a list of arguments to pass to `parse_args()`. This makes testing easier. Also, the `import` statement should still go at the top of the script, not inside `get_args` itself.

```
import argparse

# ...

def get_args(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="calculate X to the power of Y")
    # ...
    return parser.parse_args(argv)
```