# How to avoid repeated code in python class

Tags: python, python-2.7

After much effort on python class now my code working as expected.

But I used below code in every place in my script:

```
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = self.remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print resp
```

Any one can please help me to avoid using above code multiple times,  in the below code

```
class Asr:
    def __init__(self):

        ''' SSH connection Establish '''
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.net_username = net_username
        self.net_password = net_password
    def remote(self):
        self.remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
             paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.remote_conn_pre.connect(self.hostname, username=self.net_username, password=self.net_password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
        self.remote_conn = self.remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
    def disable_paging(self):
        self.remote_conn.send("terminal length 0\n")
    def inventory(self):

        self.remote()
        self.remote_conn.send("\n")
        self.remote_conn.send("ping 1.1.1.1\n")
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = self.remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print resp
        self.remote_conn.send("ping 1.1.1.1\n")
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = self.remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print resp
        self.remote_conn.send("ping 1.1.1.1\n")
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = self.remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print resp
        self.remote_conn.close()
    def version(self):
        self.remote()
        self.remote_conn.send("\n")
        self.remote_conn.send("ping 1.1.1.1\n")
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = self.remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print resp
        self.disable_paging()
        self.remote_conn.send("show inventory\n")
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('#'):
            resp = self.remote_conn.recv(9999)
            buff += resp
            print resp
        self.remote_conn.close()
asr = Asr()
asr.inventory()
asr.version()
```

Comment: Ummm..  make a function?

Comment: I dont know for some reason if make function it is not working. I mean paramiko is disconnecting . Let me try in paramiko level what is happening

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785952/python-argparse-as-a-function/26786146#26786146 for additional encouragement & theoretical base.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function same as above 
Eg:

```
def check_buff(self, buff):

    while not buff.endswith('#'):
        resp = self.remote_conn.recv(9999)
        buff += resp
        print resp
```

call the function and pass the buff parameter each time.
Eg:

```
buff = ''
self.check_buff(buff)
```